# Lining figures in sidenote marks

Tags: oldstylenums, sidenotes, liningnums

I would like my sidenote marks to be lining figures, not old-style figures. I have defined a new font family with lining figures, but how do I get this into the definition of the sidenote marks?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{realscripts}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Stone Serif.otf}
\newfontfamily{\liningmainfont}[Numbers=Lining]{Stone Serif.otf}

\begin{document}
{\liningmainfont 123} 123\sidenote{Hi there!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this line in your preamble:

```
 \renewcommand{\thesidenote}{\textsuperscript*{\liningmainfont\arabic{sidenote}}}
```

It instructs your engine to typeset the `sidenote` counter using the lining numbers.

So a MWE will look like

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{sidenotes}
 \usepackage{realscripts}

  \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Stone Serif.otf}
  \newfontfamily{\liningmainfont}[Numbers=Lining]{Stone Serif.otf}
  \renewcommand{\thesidenote}{\textsuperscript*{\liningmainfont\arabic{sidenote}}}

 \begin{document}
 {\liningmainfont 123} 123\sidenote{Hi there!}   
 \end{document}
```

Which looks like (I'm using Caslon here, since I don't have Stone Serif): [image]